# Quoting strings in System.out.println

Tags: java

I'm programming a little game and forgot how to quote a String in

`System.out.println();`

My specific Problem:

this is my initial string, it gets changed in a loop every so often to

```
String Player = "Player1";
```

Now I wanna say something like "It's Player 1's turn", but

`System.out.println(It's "Player"'s turn);` dosen't work (obiously).

Would be awesome if someone could give me a hand on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the `"`:

```
System.out.println("It's \"" + Player + "\"'s turn");
```

Or you can use the [Ascci table](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
System.out.println("It's" + (char)34 + Player + (char)34 + "'s turn");
```

Also try to follow *Java Naming Convention* and start the variables with lower case.

---

**Edit**

If you don't want to include the `"`, you simply do:

```
System.out.println("It's " + Player + "'s turn");
```

Comment: He doesn't actually want to print the `"`.

Comment: @interjay Then what he wants to print?

Comment: From the question: `I wanna say something like "It's Player 1's turn"`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to substitute the `player` variable

```
System.out.printf("It's %s's turn%n", player);
```

Comment: Yes.. that's another good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("It's " + Player + "'s turn");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like

```
System.out.println("I'ts "+player+"'s turn");
```

and use
`String player = "Player1"` instead of     `String Player = "Player1"`. The variables are started with minuscules letters.